# Unable to refresh SNAPSHOT bundle

Tags: apache-karaf

I am unable to get any of my bundles to refresh after being rebuilt with maven even though they are SNAPSHOT bundles.
My workaround is to uninstall the current bundle, increment the version in the poms (4.3.10-SNAPSHOT -> 4.3.11-SNAPSHOT), build using maven and then install the incremented version.  This is very unproductive!

Karaf version 4.2.9

A sample command to install the bundle:

```
bundle:install -f -s mvn:com.asdf/com.asdf.server.entity/4.3.12-SNAPSHOT
```

My repository path in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg is :

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
    file:///root/.m2/repository@id=DevRepo@snapshots,\
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central, \
    https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group@id=apache@snapshots@noreleases, \
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ops4j-snapshots@id=ops4j.sonatype.snapshots.deploy@snapshots@noreleases
```

I have executed `bundle:watch -i 100 *`.

The timestamp on bundles in DevRepo are updated when I build.

I have also tried stopping the bundle and using the command:  update -r XXX.

Any help in troubleshooting this issue?

Thanks,
Timothy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the mvn local repository in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg to my user/home/.m2 directory.

Thanks to jbonofre on the karaf user forums.

Timothy